# Which program is stealing my keyboard events?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm running a fairly new install of 10.04 using a happy hacker keyboard because I'm an emacs user.  I've already turned off most of the bindings in **Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** and modified the layout options there to set **Meta is mapped to Win keys**.  Everything is working well except some program is stealing <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.  This seems to cause a sort of inverse video effect in both cases, with <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> affecting only the current window and <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> affecting the entire desktop, so I suspect that this is the window manager but I can't figure out where this might be configured so I can change it.  Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've discovered Compiz' colour inversion feature.

To get rid of it, install the 
**[Compiz Configuration Settings Manager (`ccsm`)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]**,

- Go to **Negate Window Contents**
- Click on the buttons that says <kbd>Super+N</kbd> and M, for each of them

  - Remove the check mark by **Enabled**

You can also disable the feature altogether, by removing the check mark in the side bar on the left.

Comment: For some reason, ccsm is in the wrong language for me. The description "Negate Window Contents" might be slightly different for you.

Comment: You have earned my undying gratitude!